# Rails Timed Try Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, try-catch, timed

So I am using Resolver in Rails 3.1 to try to get the DHCP address of a server and I want to allow a certain time for it to query...perhaps .5 sec because it is slowing down my entire request.

This is what I have right now..

```
$begin
$Resolver('ipaddress').answer[0]
$rescue
$end
```

This currently takes a while so is there a way to say, "I want to run this snippet for 0.5 sec" and then move on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html

```
require 'timeout'

begin
  Timeout::timeout(0.5) do
    Resolver('ipaddress').answer[0]
  end
rescue Timeout::Error => e
  # do something
end
```